# Behavior of BroadcastReceiver when intent processing might overlap

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Since a statically declared BroadcastReceiver is run on the UI thread, is it safe to say that any intents that target it, but that are fired while the BroadcastReceiver is in the middle of processing a prior intent, will be queued for processing until the BroadcastReciever is finished with its processing?

Additionally, in such a scenario, will delayed intents be handled the same instance of BroadcastReceiver as the current one, or a new instance, or is there no guarantee one way or another?  Thanks!